# Keycloak Testcontainer fails due Timed out waiting for URL to be accessible (http://localhost:55127/auth should return HTTP 200)

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, testcontainers

I am using Mariadb and Keycloak test containers for integration test , however , mariadb container starts , but Keycloak container fails to start . I am using MacBook Pro M1 and jAVA 11

Code

```
public abstract class IntegrationTest {

public static KeycloakContainer keycloakContainer = new KeycloakContainer("jboss/keycloak:15.0.2")
        .withRealmImportFile("/test_realm.json");

@Autowired
public TransactionService transactionService;

@Autowired
public PaymentService paymentService;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());;

@LocalServerPort
static int port = 8088;

protected static String authToken;

@BeforeAll
public static void setUp() {
    RestAssured.port = port;
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost/";
    RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails();

    assertTrue(keycloakContainer.isRunning());

    String authServer = keycloakContainer.getAuthServerUrl();
    System.out.println("authServer: " + authServer);
    authToken = getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("authToken: " + authToken);
}

@DynamicPropertySource
static void dynamicPropertySource(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {

        MariaDBContainer<?> container = new MariaDBContainer<>("mariadb:10.6.4-focal")
                .withDatabaseName("test")
                .withUsername("test")
                .withPassword("test");
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url", container::getJdbcUrl);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", container::getUsername);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", container::getPassword);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.driver-class", () -> "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.jpa.database-platform", () -> "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect");

    dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("keycloak.auth-server-url", keycloakContainer::getAuthServerUrl);
        container.start();
    keycloakContainer.start();
    System.out.println("Containers should be started.");
}
```

}

IDE logs :

> Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
> Docker host IP address is localhost
> Connected to docker:
> Server Version: 20.10.10
> API Version: 1.41
> Operating System: Docker Desktop
> Total Memory: 1988 MB
> Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
> Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
> Checking the system...
> ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
> ✔︎ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
> Creating container for image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
> Starting container with ID: 4cb0ba7707f5cee202ae19aa177b7f2b7dbe5de93664263869935742e45c9f99
> Container mariadb:10.6.4-focal is starting: 4cb0ba7707f5cee202ae19aa177b7f2b7dbe5de93664263869935742e45c9f99
> Waiting for database connection to become available at jdbc:mariadb://localhost:55129/sympl using query 'SELECT 1'
> Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:55129/sympl)
> Container mariadb:10.6.4-focal started in PT5.679875S
> Creating container for image: jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
> Starting container with ID: 8c8792df10e2da254dd7fe200feeff4a2b756b989aec51897f6a6faca21a7403
> Container jboss/keycloak:15.0.2 is starting: 8c8792df10e2da254dd7fe200feeff4a2b756b989aec51897f6a6faca21a7403
> /festive_bhabha: Waiting for 120 seconds for URL: http://localhost:55131/auth (where port 55131 maps to container port 8080)

after that it tries to reconnect again and fails after the timeout finish .

Container logs from docker :

> ## Added 'admin' to
> '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json',
> restart server to load user
>
> Using Embedded H2 database
>
> =========================================================================
>
> =========================================================================
>
> JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
> JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/keycloak
>
> JAVA: java
>
> JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M
> -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true   --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
>
> =========================================================================
>
> 05:28:07,243 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version
> 1.11.0.Final 05:28:09,744 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final 05:28:09,890 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main)
> JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final 05:28:10,814 INFO  [org.jboss.as]
> (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 15.0.2 (WildFly Core
> 15.0.1.Final) starting 05:28:11,475 INFO  [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-4) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file
> provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this
> 05:28:14,209 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool
> -- 20) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.15.3.Final 05:28:15,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 11) WFLYCTL0033: Extension 'security' is deprecated and
> may not be supported in future versions 05:28:16,882 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot
> Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at
> address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface'
> is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the
> attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description
> operation to learn more about the deprecation. 05:28:17,062 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 23) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at
> address
> '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is
> deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute
> description in the output of the read-resource-description operation
> to learn more about the deprecation. 05:28:18,155 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating
> http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
> 05:28:18,290 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version
> 3.8.4.Final 05:28:18,332 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.4.Final 05:28:18,589 INFO
> [org.wildfly.extension.health] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36)
> WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Base Health Subsystem 05:28:18,664 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37)
> WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem. 05:28:18,689 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) WFLYSEC0002:
> Activating Security Subsystem 05:28:18,690 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming
> Subsystem 05:28:18,666 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 51) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the
> /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger
> for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the
> attribute value is unique. 05:28:18,717 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security]
> (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox
> version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-00007 05:28:18,816 INFO
> [org.wildfly.extension.metrics] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45)
> WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Base Metrics Subsystem 05:28:18,826 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0009:
> Starting Jakarta Connectors Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar
> 1.4.27.Final) 05:28:18,790 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has
> auto-configured to 8 IO threads with 64 max task threads based on your
> 4 available processors 05:28:18,887 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC
> service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.20.Final 05:28:19,009
> INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003:
> Starting Naming Service 05:28:19,010 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001:
> Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default] 05:28:19,357 INFO
> [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0003:
> Undertow 2.2.5.Final starting 05:28:19,342 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 31) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class
> org.h2.Driver (version 1.4) 05:28:19,398 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8)
> WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2 05:28:19,477
> INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39)
> WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.15.1.Final 05:28:19,667 WARN
> [org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool --
> 52) WFLYCLWEBUT0007: No routing provider found for default-server;
> using legacy provider based on static configuration 05:28:20,323 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool
> slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class),
> which is derived from thread worker pool sizing. 05:28:20,323 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool
> mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class),
> which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host. 05:28:20,527
> INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool --
> 52) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path
> '/opt/jboss/keycloak/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing:
> 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true',
> safe-symlink-paths: '[]'] 05:28:20,604 INFO
> [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012:
> Started server default-server. 05:28:20,615 WARN
> [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYELY00023:
> KeyStore file
> '/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore'
> does not exist. Used blank. 05:28:20,648 INFO
> [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) Queuing
> requests. 05:28:20,651 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC
> service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
> 05:28:20,669 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread
> 1-1) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore
> /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not
> found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self-signed
> certificate for host localhost WARNING: An illegal reflective access
> operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
> org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions
> (jar:file:/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/extension/elytron/main/wildfly-elytron-integration-15.0.1.Final.jar!/)
> to method com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider.isFIPS() WARNING:
> Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
> org.wildfly.extension.elytron.SSLDefinitions WARNING: Use
> --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
> denied in a future release 05:28:21,227 INFO
> [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006:
> Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080 05:28:23,000
> INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0493:
> Jakarta Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete 05:28:23,843
> INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service
> thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source
> [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS] 05:28:23,843 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread
> 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
> 05:28:24,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-4)
> WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches
> include: none 05:28:24,192 WARN
> [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3)
> WFLYDM0111: Keystore
> /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not
> found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed
> certificate for host localhost 05:28:24,286 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7)
> WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory
> /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments 05:28:24,309 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027:
> Starting deployment of "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name:
> "keycloak-server.war") 05:28:24,494 INFO
> [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006:
> Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443 05:28:28,673
> INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54)
> ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Corona Extra' 11.0.9.Final
> 05:28:29,231 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-7)
> ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being
> selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
> 05:28:29,250 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-7)
> ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being
> selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
> 05:28:29,578 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 55) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller
> 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.jboss.JBossMarshaller'
> 05:28:29,581 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 54) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller
> 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
> 05:28:30,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYCLINF0002: Started http-remoting-connector
> cache from ejb container 05:28:30,675 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54)
> WFLYCLINF0002: Started offlineClientSessions cache from keycloak
> container 05:28:30,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLINF0002: Started actionTokens
> cache from keycloak container 05:28:30,675 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61)
> WFLYCLINF0002: Started work cache from keycloak container 05:28:30,686
> INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool
> -- 57) WFLYCLINF0002: Started sessions cache from keycloak container 05:28:30,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authenticationSessions cache
> from keycloak container 05:28:30,726 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59)
> WFLYCLINF0002: Started loginFailures cache from keycloak container
> 05:28:30,726 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0002: Started clientSessions cache from
> keycloak container 05:28:30,726 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66)
> WFLYCLINF0002: Started offlineSessions cache from keycloak container
> 05:28:30,953 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0002: Started users cache from keycloak
> container 05:28:30,953 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0002: Started realms cache
> from keycloak container 05:28:30,956 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65)
> WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorization cache from keycloak container
> 05:28:30,959 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYCLINF0002: Started keys cache from keycloak
> container 05:28:31,726 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC
> service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0273: Excluded subsystem webservices via
> jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not exist. 05:28:31,803 ERROR
> [io.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) UT005024: Could not register
> resource change listener for caching resource manager, automatic
> invalidation of cached resource will not work:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Function not
> implemented   at
> org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.nio.WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.(WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.java:75)
> at
> org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.nio.NioXnio.createFileSystemWatcher(NioXnio.java:241)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResourceManager.registerResourceChangeListener(PathResourceManager.java:262)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletResourceManager.registerResourceChangeListener(ServletResourceManager.java:117)
> at
> io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.CachingResourceManager.(CachingResourceManager.java:64)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:567)
> at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:276)
> at
> org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
> at
> org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
> at
> org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: Function not implemented     at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.(LinuxWatchService.java:64)
> at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.newWatchService(LinuxFileSystem.java:47)
> at
> org.jboss.xnio.nio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.nio.WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.(WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.java:73)
> ... 14 more
>
> 05:28:34,143 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool
> -- 63) KC-SERVICES0001: Loading config from standalone.xml or domain.xml 05:28:34,422 WARN  [org.keycloak.common.Profile]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Deprecated feature enabled:
> upload_scripts 05:28:34,423 WARN  [org.keycloak.common.Profile]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Preview feature enabled: scripts
> 05:28:34,569 INFO  [org.keycloak.url.DefaultHostnameProviderFactory]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Frontend: , Admin:
> , Backend:  05:28:37,112 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63)
> WFLYCLINF0002: Started realmRevisions cache from keycloak container
> 05:28:37,162 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0002: Started userRevisions cache from
> keycloak container 05:28:37,209 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63)
> WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorizationRevisions cache from keycloak
> container 05:28:37,214 INFO
> [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Node name: 8c8792df10e2, Site name:
> null
>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x0000004016607605, pid=343, tid=466
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.12+7) (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
> Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
> Problematic frame:
> J 5784 c1 liquibase.exception.ValidationErrors.checkRequiredField(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
> (120 bytes) @ 0x0000004016607605
> [0x00000040166075c0+0x0000000000000045]
>
> **No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java**
> **again**
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
> /tmp/hs_err_pid343.log Compiled method (c1)   35858 6315       2       liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.CreateSequenceGenerator::validate (169
> bytes)  total in heap  [0x00000040166ecb90,0x00000040166ee598] = 6664
> relocation     [0x00000040166ecd08,0x00000040166ece38] = 304  main
> code      [0x00000040166ece40,0x00000040166ee0a0] = 4704  stub code
> [0x00000040166ee0a0,0x00000040166ee130] = 144  oops
> [0x00000040166ee130,0x00000040166ee160] = 48  metadata
> [0x00000040166ee160,0x00000040166ee178] = 24  scopes data
> [0x00000040166ee178,0x00000040166ee2a8] = 304  scopes pcs
> [0x00000040166ee2a8,0x00000040166ee528] = 640  dependencies
> [0x00000040166ee528,0x00000040166ee530] = 8  nul chk table
> [0x00000040166ee530,0x00000040166ee598] = 104 Could not load
> hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%208&component=java-11-openjdk
> qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
> *** JBossAS process (343) received ABRT signal ***

however, when I start the keycloack container and setExposedPort(8080)

```
keycloakContainer.setExposedPorts(List.of(8080));
keycloakContainer.start();
```

the container logs doesn't raise JVM error . here the logs are after exposing 8080 port

Answer (score 5):

The `jboss/keycloak` images only support `linux/amd64` architectures. See the [tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/tags) inside Docker Hub.

With your M1, you have an `arm64` processor that's not supported by the official Keycloak images. With Apple's Rosetta 2 emulation, Apple tries best effort to make an `amd64` image work, but your Keycloak container fails during startup:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x0000004016607605, pid=343, tid=466

You can use a community build that supports `arm64`:

- https://github.com/richardjkendall/keycloak-arm
- https://hub.docker.com/r/mihaibob/keycloak

```java
public static KeycloakContainer keycloakContainer = 
    new KeycloakContainer("mihaibob/keycloak:14.0.0")
            .withRealmImportFile("/test_realm.json");
```

You should also [be able to build](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5310#issuecomment-877653653) your own `arm64` compatible Keycloak Docker image locally.

Comment: Perfect! You can mark this answer as the correct answer so that future visitors can easily navigate to it.